# Uploading data to server using xmlhttp request

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xmlhttprequest

I am new to javascript and jquery.What i want to achieve is to upload multiple images on to a  server.I am aware of similar questions asked earlier but unfortunately they did not help me much.I want to upload images on to the server using a xml-http request object.Any example with some explanation which makes use of this will be very helpful.Any sort of help is really appreciated.Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

you can use ajaxUpload plugin which has progress bar, multiple file select and drag and drop functionality:

http://valums.com/ajax-upload/

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply,i appreciate it.but i'll be using xml/json based webservices to upload the file.If u can direct me to any such example i'll be very thankful.